# How to make new.json.rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, rabl

I want to generate new.json.rabl page to create new post
first of all i created in post folder new.json.rabl file

```
object @post
attributes :content, :photo
```

and localhost:3000/post/new.json return

```
{"post":{"content":null,"photo":null}}
```

how can i send content and photo values to rabl

Comment: looks like your `@post` variable is `nil`

Comment: Yes it's nil i want to pass parameters to it

Comment: i suggest you read [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a method new in your posts controller. There, if you want rabl to render the content and photo values, you need to put:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new(content: "some_content", photo: "some_photo")
  render('path_to_your_rabl_file', formats: :json) # or respond_with(@post) if the routes are correct
end
```